# Which is the best way to install Moses for SMT?

Tags: deep-learning, machine-translation

I have tried many ways but it always ended up in error. My Configuration: Ubuntu 16.04, Python 3.6.10 The error that I am unable to solve is: undefined reference to

```
boost::unit_test::unit_test_main(bool (*)(), int, char**)
```

I was initially following this guide [here](https://achrafothman.net/site/how-to-install-moses-statistical-machine-translation-in-ubuntu/) but had to tweak the commands a lot. Still, unable to settle things off.